# Bigquery Improving the accuracy problems

Tags: google-bigquery

We have a problem to improve the accuracy of BigQuery, our case of use is the following, we are using a table of 1,600 million record, a table not to large for our issues, and we are trying to find unique users.

Firstly we thought to use a "count distinct", but as the documentation told for a large amount of data you obtain an estimate result. In order to improve this, we are tried "count + group by"  in place of "count distinct" statement. But the result of bigquery is too large response. We have grouped by UserID firstly, and we have continued with this idea but reducing the number of data, choosing a specific campaing, decrementing considerably the amount of data. But the result is the same, response too large.

Any idea or opinion about how to obtain unique users, with accuray in bigQuery?

Answer (score 3):

`COUNT(DISTINCT field)` returns an approximate answer, as you've realized. You can improve the accuracy by using `COUNT(DISTINCT field, n)` for a large value of N. The larger this value, the more accurate the result will be, although it may run into 'result too large' errors if you set it too high.

You can get the exact unique count by using GROUP EACH BY. This may make it difficult to calculate other values in the same query, but GROUP EACH BY will work on any size table. For example:

```
select count(*) from (select field from dataset.table GROUP EACH BY field)
```

Comment: It is a shame not to improve the accuracy of the results, nor have the exact error rate function. Anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: Artemis - the answer has changed since originally answered in 2012. You can get arbitrarily large unique results now.